# MATLAB - Remove NaN elements in cell array. Help to speed up a function

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, nan, cell-array

I need help to speed up this function I created to remove NaN elements in a cell array.

To explain better my function with an example. Let's suppose we have a cell array of I have a cell array on the form `indx{ii}` where each `ii` is an array of size `1xNii` (this means the arrays have different size) with `NaN` elements on it.

```
datawithNaN{1}=[1,4,8,6];
datawithNaN{2}=[4,6,2];
datawithNaN{3}=[9,8,NaN];
datawithNaN{4}=[3,NaN,NaN];
datawithNaN{5}=[NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN];
```

What I want the function function to do is remove all NaN elements in the cell array. So the answer for the example should be:

```
datawithoutNaN{1}=[1,4,8,6];
datawithoutNaN{2}=[4,6,2];
datawithoutNaN{3}=[9,8];
datawithoutNaN{4}=[3];
datawithoutNaN{5}=[];
```

So far I have written a function that gives me the result I want but it takes too much time specially when working with big cell arrays or big arrays inside the cell array.
My function is:

```
function result = rmNaN(datawithNaN)

[row_cell, col_cell] = size(datawithNaN);
result = cell(row_cell, col_cell);
for i=1:row_cell
    for j=1:col_cell
        [row,col]=size(datawithNaN{i,j});
        if col>row
            datawithNaN{i,j}=datawithNaN{i,j}';
            [row,~]=size(datawithNaN{i,j});
        end
        for k=1:row
            if ~isnan(datawithNaN{i,j}(k))
                result{i,j}(k) = datawithNaN{i,j}(k);
            else
                continue
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this with `cellfun`.

```
datawithoutNaN = cellfun(@(x)x(~isnan(x)), datawithNaN, 'uniform', 0);
```

This goes through each element of the cell array, uses `isnan` to determine which elements in the array are `NaN` and yields a logical array the same size as `x` where it is `true` where it is a `NaN` and `false` otherwise. It then negates this and uses it as a logical index to grab only the non-`Nan` values and return them. The `'uniform'` input ensures that the result is also a cell array.

Comment: I tried it and it works perfect! And simpler than what I had written! Thanks :).